# Callback Hell, if/else to call a different callback

Tags: node.js

I have a function like this one :

```
MngService.getByKey(service, function(service) {
  if (service === null) return res.json(STATUS_ERROR);
  MngUser.login(login, pass, function(user) {
    if (user === null) return res.json(STATUS_ERROR);
    MngToken.replaceTokenForServiceIdAndUserId(service.id, user.id, function(token) {
      if (!token) return res.json(STATUS_ERROR);
      return res.json(STATUS_SUCCESS);
    });
  });
});
```

I'd like to change my `MngUser.login` function depending on a if/else test.
The only solution I found for now is :

```
var loginFunc;
if (something)
{
  loginFunc = function (login, pass, token, cb) {
    return MngUser.loginWithPassword(login, pass, cb);
  };
}
else {
  loginFunc = function (login, pass, token, cb) {
    return MngUser.loginWithToken(token, cb);
  };
}

MngService.getByKey(service, function(service) {
  if (service === null) return res.json(STATUS_ERROR);
  loginFunc(login, pass, token, function(user) {
    if (user === null) return res.json(STATUS_ERROR);
    MngToken.setSsoTokenForUserId(user.id, function(sso_token) {
      if (!token) return res.json(STATUS_ERROR);
      return res.json(STATUS_SUCCESS);
    });
  });
});
```

I wonder if this way of doing it is good or if there is a better design pattern to handle this situation in Node.JS as I find it a bit hard to read and error-prone

Comment: Where are `login`, `pass` and `token` coming from? It seems like you have some scope hell going on, you should probably clear that up first.

Comment: they are post parameter sent from a client in the same request.

Comment: In that case, it sounds to me like you should have different routers (or different callbacks inside the same router) handling different login methods. i.e. `/login/creds` for user:password, `/login/token` for token, etc.

Comment: The problem if I have different routers is that the logic is repeated multiple times (get the service by Key, update a token, and there is other stuff I cutted out) leading to many functions with the same copy/pasted code with only the line calling the login function changing

Comment: In that case, you can create a function that accepts a login function and returns a route function. `function loginRoute(loginFn) { return function() { /* use loginFn here */ }; }` then go `express.post('/token', loginRoute(myTokenFunc)); express.post('/creds', loginRoute(myCredentialsLoginFunc));`

Comment: Ok, you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: I sadly can't at the moment :( will do when I get home. Maybe someone will think of an even better way by then.